# Check string contains attribute from array list

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

Hey I am writing a calculator script in Java.
I am currently stuck trying to find out a way to find if any of the characters in a sting are in an ArrayList.

For example:
I have to have the input as a String I pass this string into a method of which has access to an array list with the operators and operands in it. How can I make sure that the string only contains the operands and operators within this array list?

Thanks, Ciaran

Here is the code that I have so far with the input being passed in..

```
import java.util.*;
public class stringCalculator {

private String[] operators = {"+","-","/","*"};

public stringCalculator(String userinput){

    System.out.println(userinput);

    public boolean checkInput(){

    }

}

}
```

Here is the new code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class stringCalculator {

private String userinput;
HashSet<String> op = new HashSet<String>();

public stringCalculator(String userinput){
    this.userinput = userinput;
    //System.out.println(userinput);
    HashSet<String> op = new HashSet<String>();
    op.add("+");
    op.add("-");
    op.add("*");
    op.add("/");
    this.op = op;

    System.out.println(op);
}
public void checkTheInput(){
    System.out.println(userinput);
}

public boolean checkInput(){
    return op.contains(userinput);

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edited to meet requirement as per comments

To return true if a string contains only `-+/*` or digits:

```
public boolean checkInput(String input) {
    return input.matches("[-+/*0-9]+");
}
```

This uses a regular expression to assert that the string contains only the specified characters. A breakdown of the regex:

- `[...]` is a *character class*, which lists the characters allowed
- `+` means "one or more of the preceding expression" (in this case the character class)

Note that the minus sign in a character class is for a *range* of characters, eg `0-9` means `0123456789`. However, when a minus is used either first of last in a character class, it means a *literal* minus (not a range).

Another note about `String.matches()` - it must match the *whole* string to return true. This is different from many other languages, where the similar method/function would return true if *part* of the string matches.

Comment: This simply checks if the string is in the array list. I was more looking to see if any single element of the string are in the list?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the string contains any of the characters `+-/*`?

Comment: Anything other than +-/* ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to return true if the string contains any characters other than `+-/*`?

Comment: I want it to return true if it only contains +-/* and 0-9 and false if contains anything else. So 3+2-3 would be true but as+2f would be false

Comment: Im not sure you understand. So they can enter any numbers or operands and if there is any thing else in there other than them it returns false.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've updated the answer with an explanation, in case you are unfamiliar with regex

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to take out the numbers, and then check if the remaining characters are all contained in `opereators`. Assuming your input String is not too long, I'd suggest you use a `HashSet` instead of String[] for `operators`. This way, you can use the `[contains(Object)][1]` method (which will be O(1) instead of O(n)) for anything that's not a number in your String.

As validation goes, however, you'll still have to check for much more, such as: "4++5/-3", where the operands are valid, but the overall expression isn't.

Comment: I was going to make another array list called operands containing all the numbers to check for as well.

Comment: That's fine, just use HashSet. You see, checking if something is in an `ArrayList` means you have to go through each element sequentially, which takes time proportional to n if n is the number of operators. If you use a HashSet instead, however, the checks are closer to constant time regardless of the number of operators (what's called O(1))

Comment: I put the new code in my question. This works but only if the operator is the only thing in the string. I just want to write this method to make sure that the String will not contain anything but operators and operands. I will add 0-9 to the HashSet once it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate expressions such as:

> (3+4)*5

(which is in INFIX format). it is not very wise to read the string straightly. you should first convert the input to POSTFIX or Reverse Polish  format like:

> 34+5*

This can be done  reading characters one by one and using a stack. In that case you can check the characters on the fly one by one storing operators in a Set or Map.

I would recommend having a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation for POSTFIX format and http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Java/Infix_Postfix_Converter.html
for example conversion code.

Comment: Thanks, yes I will be converting to RPN however at the moment I just want a method that will check that the user hasn't input any characters that are not operators or operands.

Comment: So in that case, it does not make sense to scan all characters at once. While converting to RPN you will be getting characters one by one. You can check whether they are legal or illegal then.

Comment: As easier as that would be as part of my work it is required that I make a method to check first! Thanks though!